# System shutdown/reboot through arduino?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, arduino

I am wondering if there is a way to write arduino code to ask Ubuntu to shutdown/reboot over serial communication. Basically, I want to use a Bluetooth sensor connected to an arduino, to be able to shutdown the computer. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Aditya

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want to set up a service on the host machine to wait for a shutdown signal, and then shut down.

Run this in Terminal:

```
sudo echo "cat /dev/ttyS0 
poweroff" > /etc/sbin/sshutdownd
sudo chmod 755 /etc/sbin/sshutdownd
```

And then just run this at boot (you can throw it in an init.d script if you want):

```
nohup /etc/sbin/sshutdownd &
```

On the arduino, just send a return carriage on the serial line, and the system will shut down.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! one more question. What is a return carriage, and how do i send it via an arduino?

Comment: The equivalent of pressing enter.